# Elasticsearch Bulk indexing using Perl LWP module

Tags: elasticsearch

the below is the subroutine for sending request to bulk 
it takes input as json  and outputs result

```
 sub BulkJSON(){
                    my $json=@_[1];
                    #$id = lc $id; # Convert to lowercase as Elastic doesn't support uppercase ids
                    my $uri = $base_url.'/_bulk';
                    my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );
                    $req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
                    $req->content($json);

                    my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
                    my $response = $browser->request($req);

                    $html = $response->content()."\n";

                    return "$html";
                }
```

Comment: could you post relevant portion of the code snippet

Comment: sub BulkJSON(){
 my $json=@_[1];
 #$id = lc $id; # Convert to lowercase as Elastic doesn't support uppercase ids
 my $uri = $base_url.'/_bulk';
 my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );
 $req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
 $req->content($json);

 my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 my $response = $browser->request($req);

 $html = $response->content()."\n";

 return "$html";
}

Comment: please apologise for pasting code in comment section I m a newbie

Comment: could you `print  $json` to show how a sample request body looks

Comment: @keety I figured it out its because malformed json string thanks